# Dispatch different parameters to different classes with single interface

Tags: python, object-oriented, functional-programming

I have a set of classes that have similar funcionality but very different interfaces. I created two interface classes with polymorphic methods so I can operate over then. When creating calling the methods, I have to pass a set of parameters, in this case a JSON file, that is also different for each class. Is there a way to create a generic interface without having to do ifs to select which parameter to pass to each class?

```
import library_A
import library_B
import json

class ApproachA():

    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params
        self.entity = library_A.Model(self.params)

    def run(self, data):
        return self.entity(data)


class ApproachB():

    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = parse_params(params)
        self.entity = library_B.Model(self.params)

    def run(self, data):
        real_data = do_something(data)
        return self.entity(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('params.json') as f:
        params = json.loads(f)

    entity_list = []
    # here lies the problem
    for key, param in params.items():
        if key == "model_a":
            entity_list.append(Approach_A(param))
        elif key == "model_b":
            entity_list.append(Approach_B(param))
```

while the JSON parameter file is as follows:

```
{
    "model_a": {"param_1":10, "param_2":22},
    "model_b": {"thing":"strudel", "param_cc": 102, "talk":False}
}
```

I definitely want to avoid these ifs sequences and couplings, as things similar to these tests have to be done in several places in the code. I also would like to avoid an abstract base class. I´m trying to keep things as functional as possible, without heavy OO concepts.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `transpose` on a dict. I'm confused - why is this expected to work?

Comment: Does the JSON file contain both model_a and model_b data always? Or are you combining the data further up/earlier in the procedure?

Comment: I´ll be combining the data further, this is just a demonstration of my process.

Comment: `transpose` here was supposed to represent an operation done on the data, to show that the two interface classes are distinct. I´ll edit the code to be more realistic.

Comment: Why don't you simply define `params = {ApproachA: {"param_1": 10, …}, …}`?

Comment: Usually the parameter dict here is a external JSON file and i would need to do an eval, right?